# How to solve this trig equation without using the double angle formula for tangent?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> If $$\begin{cases}
> \tan(x+y)=3\\ 
> \tan(x-y)=2, 
> \end{cases}$$ find a value of $\tan(2x)$

I have (1) added (and subtracted) the 2 expressions above, having expanded them into formulaic notion, (2) separately solved them and substituted one of them into the other one, but to no avail. I want to know the correct way of solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}\tan(2x)&=\tan\bigl((x+y)+(x-y)\bigr)\\&=\frac{\tan(x+y)+\tan(x-y)}{1-\tan(x+y)\tan(x-y)}\\&=\frac{3+2}{1-3\times2}=-1.\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

A little variation of JCS's solution:
$$\tan{(x+y)}=\tan{(2x-(x-y))}=\frac{\tan{2x}-2}{1+2\tan{2x}}=3\Rightarrow \tan{2x}=-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tan{x}=a$ and $\tan{y}=b$.

Hence, $\frac{a+b}{1-ab}=3$ and $\frac{a-b}{1+ab}=2$.

From here we'll get $a^2-2a-1=0$, which gives $a=1+\sqrt2$ or $a=1-\sqrt2$,

which gives $x=67.5^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$ or $x=-22.5^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$,

which says that $\tan2x=-1$.

I think the José Carlos Santos's solution is much better.